# What's with Constraints in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint, swiftui

What is happening now with *constraints* in `SwiftUI`? Do `View` types adapt automatically for bigger devices etc. or what should we have to do instead?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

### RIP, Constraints!

*SwiftUI* doesn't use layout constraints. *UIKit* is still around, it's not deprecated and fully functional, so if you continue to use the classic approach, you can use as many constraints as you wish.

However, if you choose to go with *SwiftUI* → rest in peace, constraints!

[image: Tomb Stone with "RIP Constraints" inscription]

The core concept to align views with each other is using stacks:

- *[HStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/hstack)*
- *[VStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack)*

If you want to overlay views (i.e. put one view on top of another), you can use a

- *[ZStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/zstack)*

The *[View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view)* protocol itself ([to which all view types mysteriously conform](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56470614/2062785)) has tons of functions called *modifiers* that you can use to customize your view's layout.

---

### Examples

Here are some examples how you can achieve specific layouts with those modifiers compared to  using constraints:

#### 1. Aspect Ratio

Instead of

```
view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2)
```

in *UIKit* you would write

```
view
    .aspectRatio(2, contentMode: .fit)
```

in *SwiftUI*.

#### 2. Spacing Between Views

Instead of

```
view2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view1.leadingAnchor, constant: 8)
```

in *UIKit* you could arrange the views in a horizontal stack and add a spacer between them and add the `frame` modifier to specify its width:

```
HStack {
    view1
    Spacer()
        .frame(width: 30)
    view2
}
```

#### 3. Equal Widths

This is where it gets more complicated. You can no longer specify that two views have an equal width. If they are in the same vertical stack (i.e. aligned in a vertical line), fine: just set the `contentMode` to `.fill` and control the actual width by setting the stack view's width → mission accomplished. ✅ But if they are not (for example, when they are in a horizontal stack), you have to find other ways to express that. The actual implementation will depend on the concrete layout you're trying to describe.

---

The general idea of *SwiftUI* is to keep views as small as possible and compose them. There's a little trade-off here: You pay the price that "constraints" between views in different view hierarchies get a lot more verbose to implement, the ultimate gain is that the layout is declarative and the code to create the most common user interfaces is dramatically simplified.

---

### Screen Adaptation / Responsiveness

Custom views fill the entire available space by default, which means that the top most view automatically fills the entire screen – regardless of the actual screen size. You can use *modifiers* to change that behavior.

Comment: In other words, constraints are still there but SwiftUI generates them.

Comment: @Sulthan not necessarily. SwiftUI is a dedicated framework, like UIKit. Because SwiftUI is in beta, however, it still uses a lot of UIKit components so it often seems that SwiftUI is a high-level UIKit API. But eventually SwiftUI will be totally independent from UIKit with its own methodologies under the hood.

Comment: How can I set the contentMode to .fill on the VStack ? Can't find a modifier for that

Comment: @jsbeginnerNodeJS With: `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)`

Comment: I think swiftUI is still using constraints for somethings like context menus. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59254236/do-swiftui-context-menus-use-layoutconstraints

Comment: I don't think I would agree with "the code to create the most common user interfaces is dramatically simplified" if its difficult to make two buttons that are sitting horizontal to each other have the same width

Comment: Having `in UIKit you would write` before a SwiftUI example in your *1.* is confusing.

Answer (score 10):

It still has constraint, in WWDC examples we saw `HStack` and `VStack`, which seems like `UIStackView`, so my guess it just clips to edges. You can still add padding to views so if you want constraint a `UILabel` (Text) 10pt to left you do something like this:

```
Text("Hello World").padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are very well gone, which is great, but there is something called .padding(), which can do some sort of constraint look by putting it on the left side with something like leading parameters which make an image go to the side of a view

```
struct ContentView: View {
   var body: some View {
      Image("x")
         .padding(.leading)
 
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```