# How do view types like Text or Image conform to the View protocol in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, view, swiftui, opaque-result-type

There is one big thing that confuses me about view types in *SwiftUI*:

They don't seem to conform to the `View` protocol, but somehow, they mysteriously do.

Take the `Text` type for example. It's defined as follows:

```
public struct Text : Equatable { ... }
```

I can't find any public extension that adds conformance to the `View` protocol, like

```
extension Text: View { ... }
```

and the *Relationships* section in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text#relationships) simply states:

> **Conforms To:** *Equatable*

Nothing more, that's all.

Yet, I can return an instance of `Text` where some `View` is required, for example:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("I'm a View, I swear!") 
}
```

If `Text` didn't conform to `View`, this wouldn't be possible and throw a compiler error.

*(`some View` is an **opaque result type** which means it's a specific type with an identity, but one that conforms to `View`.)*

So how is this possible?

#### Where is the `View` protocol conformance specified for *SwiftUI* view types (like `Text`, `Image`, `Circle`, ...)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question was asked on June 6, 2019, during WWDC, when we only had the first beta of Xcode 11 and SwiftUI. So answering this question correctly requires access to that version of SwiftUI. You can [download Xcode 11 beta 1 here](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/WWDC_2019/Xcode_11_Beta/Xcode_11_Beta.xip). (Thank you, [xcodereleases.com](https://xcodereleases.com/)!) You are in for an adventure trying to unpack the archive, though, because (I think) it was signed with a certificate that has since expired. I resorted to black magic (stepping through the `xip` command in LLDB and modifying memory at a key moment to subvert the certificate verification). You could perhaps just set your system time back to June 6, 2019 before unpacking.

Anyway, here's the secret to understanding why `Text` didn't appear to conform to `View`: [Xcode, and Apple's documentation generator, intentionally omit identifiers in the SDK that start with `_`.](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2f5492f572818e728e3358c13315c2d4e5c9be64/docs/ReferenceGuides/UnderscoredAttributes.md#_show_in_interface)

So if you want to see the full public declaration of a type, you cannot rely on Xcode or the documentation to show it to you. Instead, you have to dig up the `.swiftinterface` file for the module. For SwiftUI, you can find it here, relative to the `Xcode.app` directory:

```
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Modules/SwiftUI.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftinterface
```

In the Xcode 11 beta 1 version of that file, you won't find a direct conformance `Text: View`. Instead, you will find this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Text : _UnaryView {
  public static func _makeView(view: _GraphValue<Text>, inputs: _ViewInputs) -> _ViewOutputs
  public typealias Body = Swift.Never
}
```

And you will find that `_UnaryView` is a sub-protocol of `View`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public protocol _UnaryView : SwiftUI.View where Self.Body : SwiftUI._UnaryView {
}
```

So, in Xcode 11 beta 1 and the corresponding iOS, macOS, tvOS, and watchOS betas, `Text` conforms to `View` indirectly, through its conformance to `_UnaryView`. Since `_UnaryView` is part of the SDK and begins with `_`, Xcode and the Apple documentation hide that symbol. So you can't see the conformance through normal methods.

At some later point (but still, I believe, during the Xcode 11.0 beta period), Apple eliminated the `_UnaryView` protocol and made `Text` conform directly to `View`. So if you check the SwiftUI `.swiftinterface` file in Xcode 11.4 (the current version as I write this), you'll find this:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Text : SwiftUI.View {
  public static func _makeView(view: SwiftUI._GraphValue<SwiftUI.Text>, inputs: SwiftUI._ViewInputs) -> SwiftUI._ViewOutputs
  public typealias Body = Swift.Never
}
```

Comment: Brilliant to-the-point answer. Thanks for going through all that trouble to solve this seeming contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

As you know there are 2 types are Views..

1. Primitive view: `Text`, `Image`, `Circle` etc
2. Container view: `List`, `HStack`, `VStack` etc

That said, below is an extension for `Text`, Body is set to Never which means its not allowed to have a body because it is a primitive view that is meant for ending body cycle.

So,(per my understanding) at runtime SwiftUI wraps `Text` inside a container view when it finds a primitive view not being inside a container view.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension Text {

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    public typealias Body = Never
}
```

Comment: Yeah, while that might be true, it doesn't answer the question where the `View` conformance is specified. That's happening at compile time, not at runtime. Otherwise the code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Actually you're missing the View conformance in that copied extension. extension Text : View is what it says. It conforms via extensions is the answer. It right there in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI view types ARE conforming to the `View` protocol, otherwise as you mentioned the code wouldn't compile. I found some of these which were available in SwiftUI public extensions:

`Image` type has an extension which directly conforms to `View`:

```
extension Image : View {
}
```

`Circle` conforms to `Shape`, which itself conforms to `View`:

```
public struct Circle : Shape {
  ...
}

public protocol Shape : Equatable, Animatable, View {
  ...
}
```

Comment: "SwiftUI view types ARE conforming to the View protocol" → That is the assumption under which I asked the question. But _where_ exactly is that conformance defined? For `Circle` you answer that question, but what about `Text` for example or `HStack`?

Answer (score 0):

The extensions.

```
   extension Text : View {

    /// The type of view representing the body of this view.
    ///
    /// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
    /// implementation of the required `body` property.
    public typealias Body = Never
}
```