# How to create instance struct from a Protocol using associatedtype in swift?

Tags: swift

I made a protocol like this:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype Body: MyProtocol
  var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

Then I want make **MyStruct** conform to **MyProtocol**, but I am unable to return the body, how can I return the body to make codes works?

```
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    var body: some MyProtocol {
        
    }
}
```

the errors:

> Property declares an opaque return type, but has no initializer expression from which to infer an underlying type

> Missing return in accessor expected to return 'some MyProtocol'

Comment: You are trying to use the pattern established by the `View` protocol of `SwiftUI`. There is some subtlety involved, because `View` has [hidden requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166327/77567). You might get better help if explain what you want `MyProtocol` to actually represent and give some examples of real types that would conform to it, because the name `MyProtocol` is meaningless.

Comment: @MagicCode as you say, the question is a bit chicken or egg, which is why you are unlikely to get an answer you want.  Unless you can give a more concrete use case your learning point may be that this pattern is impractical ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually return something in `body`.
You've just left it empty.

Return something that conforms to `MyProtocol`, like `MyStruct` itself.

```swift
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    var body: some MyProtocol {
        return MyStruct()
    }
}
```

Comment: But that would be infinitely loop.

Comment: No, `body` is a computed  property so the second instance will not be created until you call `body`. It’s recursive yes, but not an infinite loop.

Comment: It is a loop, if I try make use of your code the app would crash because of infinity loop, and let think for sec that you are right, how could be returning `MyStruct()` be useful here, do not get me wrong, you are solving the error but there would no use for MyStruct when you return itself again. If you could return some kind of primitives that conform to MyProtocol that would be the final and correct answer.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re trying to achieve with this anyway. Because of the recursive nature of this protocol you need to return a base case at some point.

Comment: Your answer does solve the error but that make no use returning the same struct in a loop, that is the why your answer cannot be the correct one.

Comment: The protocol is recursive by its very nature, so there's no way to create a "primitive" that wouldn't also have to satisfy the requirement of `MyProtocol`. Please see the [answer linked by rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166327/3261161). It would be helpful to know what problem you're actually trying to solve.