# How to return custom primitive struct while protocol needs certain conformation to the protocol for escaping the required conformation?

Tags: swift

This is my custom protocol:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype Body: MyProtocol
  var body: Self.Body { get }
}
```

and if I want normally make a struct for conforming the protocol that would be like:

```
struct MyStruct: MyProtocol {
    var body: some MyProtocol {
        
    }
}
```

As you can see struct needs to conform to protocol and returning the body, since there is no other struct that conform to protocol, I have to make at least one custom primitive struct that it returns Never and use that one very first custom primitive struct for the body of **MyStruct**. This very first custom primitive cannot have a body and that is the point Xcode knows this the end of searching for body because if there is no custom primitive struct Xcode or my code would be in infinitely loop for looking the body.

So the goal is building a struct that I can pass that to the body **MyStruct** without having the body to return. If you need an example to understand the question is more like to making **Color** struct in SwiftUI as a primitive struct for using in our **ContentView**. The goal of this question is building this very first primitive as said like Color.

Comment: What is a “primitive struct”?

Comment: The struct that conforms to MyProtocol and I can use that struct as a return in body of MyStruct, but MyProtocol cannot ask about its body, because there is no body to return. Primitive struct would be the key to stoping protocol for asking the body.

Comment: No, the primitive is the right word.

Comment: You need to stop being so rude in every response, and go learn how what you want to emulate works: [How do view types like Text or Image conform to the View protocol in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56470614/how-do-view-types-like-text-or-image-conform-to-the-view-protocol-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really struggling to understand your use case here but here is something I think moves you in the right direction. "Never" as I understand it is effectively a view that never returns and is the end point of SwitfUI view generation behind the scenes. As a view it has a body returning never and so you can conform it to your protocol and then use it as the end of chain return you are looking for. Hard to test or understand further without context of what you are using this for but this code passes checks.

An important update missed originally, is that the final struct body can not have the body called. The Never type means it will never return.... To comply with this you need something in the getter eg. fatalError() which will terminate the app if called.

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
  associatedtype Body: MyProtocol
  var body: Self.Body { get }
}

extension Never: MyProtocol {

}

struct NoReturn: MyProtocol {
   var body: Never {
       fatalError()
   }
}
```