# Do SwiftUI Context Menus use LayoutConstraints?

Tags: swiftui

I was under the assumption that SwiftUI no longer uses NSLayoutContstraints. However I am getting constraint errors in console.  Anyone have any idea how to debug?

The following prints out if with the list view when I open the context menu:

> 2019-12-09 10:52:52.029091-0700 ContextMenuTest[26384:13138419] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
>       Try this: 
>           (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
>           (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
>       (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
>   (
>       "",
>       "= 44   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x7fd98781de00 )>",
>       "",
>       "",
>       "",
>       ""
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>   = 44   (active, names: groupView.actionsSequence...:0x7fd98781de00 )>
>
> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("one")
            Text("two")
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Text("test")
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

> I was under the assumption that SwiftUI no longer uses
>   NSLayoutContstraints.

This is simply **not** true. `SwiftUI` still uses `UIKit` components if you inspect the view hierarchy, and most components do not have exposed constraints. But some "bridged" views have `NSLayoutConstraints` for their base `UIView` classes under the hood.

Your issue is also seen by some components like alerts, popovers and context menus, as these are complex and so have not been fully ported.

Using a symbolic breakpoint for `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints`:

```
po UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.constraints
```

(`UIWindow` is a subclass of `UIView`) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwindow.

The root hosting controller and its subviews have no constraints as they have been fully ported to SwiftUI new Environment Variable syntax.

```
po UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view.constraints
```

Many runtime libraries of SwiftUI still have `NSLayoutConstraints`. See: [context menu](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIInterfaceActionGroupView.h), [alert view](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/fbb634c78269b0169efdead80955ba64eaaa2f21/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/_UIAlertControllerView.h) and so on.

Note you need to switch to the main stack frame in order to be able to access `UIApplication.shared` (`AppDelegate`). See below:

[Debug Navigator snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XByOH.png)

**How to inspect the view hierarchy?**

Using `dump`, allows you to see the SwiftUI info (more than po):

```
po dump(UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController)
```

The UIKit bridging classes are listed for the controller, e.g

```
contextMenuBridge: Optional(<_TtGC7SwiftUI17ContextMenuBridgeV33Demo11ContentView_: 0x600002c8c720>)
      ▿ some: <_TtGC7SwiftUI17ContextMenuBridgeV33Demo11ContentView_: 0x600002c8c720> #81
        - super: NSObject
        ▿ host: Optional(<_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV33Demo11ContentView_: 0x7fccd7403690; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000006f0d20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000008b5180>>)
          ▿ some: <_TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewV33Demo11ContentView_: 0x7fccd7403690; frame = (0 0; 414 896); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000006f0d20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000008b5180>> #0
        ▿ presentedMenuID: SwiftUI.ViewIdentity
          - seed: 0
        - interaction: nil
        - cachedPreferences: 0 elements
        ▿ seed: empty
          - value: 0
        - currentPreference: nil
        - cachedPlatformActions: 0 elements
        - cachedPreview: nil
    - accessibilityEnabled: false
    - cachedAccessibilityNodes: 0 elements
    - accessibilityNeedsUpdate: true
    - scrollTest: nil
    - delegate: nil
    - parentAccessibilityElement: nil
```

Similar window constraints can be found for alerts, sheets and other "bridged" classes.

Fix the error using:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows[0].translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Note however that these bridges may be removed once SwiftUI matures and comes out of beta.

Comment: The fix didn't help in my case ... Tried it in different places (like SceneDelegate or in SwiftUI file directly)